# Fancybox works locally but not online get (404)

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I got a weird problem with a clients site, they moved servers without telling me and since then Fancybox doesn't work.

All the code is unchanged and still works locally, but not on the website anymore. I get 404 for the 3 fancybox files although the file path and structure stays the same:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

Troubleshooting in the browser gives me:
www.website.com/javascript/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js & css 404 not found. I tried it with a / at the start of the href and also with direct http link but all 3 don't work.

Any ideas? Could it be a configuration problem on the server-side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: no php it is actually just a very simple static site

Comment: linux server or windows?if its linux server its case sensitive.verify case once

Comment: double checked, path is also in correct cases

Comment: solved - i just moved the fancybox files to a own folder in root, javascript folder was acting weird in general